# MS project: Roll Up Summary Name does not appear on gantt chart

Tags: task, summary, ms-project, rollup

I have the following Roll Up summary task:

```
1 - Storage Server
1.1 - PREP Phase
1.1.1 - Pre Checks
1.1.2 - Backup
1.1.3 - Shutdown

1.2 - MOVE Phase
1.2.1 - Physical Move

1.3 - POST Phase
1.3.1 - Power Up
1.3.2 - Post Checks
```

I would like to have the name of the main summary task `Storage Server` to appear on my `Gantt Chart`, to the left of the rollup bar and the resource name on the right of the rollup bar.

So far I managed to get the names of all subtaks 1.x and 1.x.x to appear on my chart but I cannot make it work for the main summary task.

Can someone help?
This is what I am trying to achieve:

[Roll Up Task Names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTzXW.png)

Thank you
Nantia